# Add a new value inside the State object in React Hook

Tags: reactjs

I have a data and I put it in the state and I want to add a new value in addition to the content of the data in the object called `watched`, but this is a problem, thank you for your help.

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import ListManager from "./component/manager";

const App = () => {
  const [getMovies, setMovie] = useState([]);
  const [getLoading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("http://my-json-server.typicode.com/bemaxima/fake-api/movies")
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((response) => {
        setMovie(response);
        setLoading(false);
      });
  });
  useEffect(() => {
    return () => {
      setMovise(
        getMovies.map((item) => ({
          id: item.id,
          text: item.name,
          rate: item.rate,
          watched: false,
        }))
      );
    };
  });

  if (getLoading) {
    return "Please wait...";
  }
  return <ListManager movies={getMovies} />;
};

export default App;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need the second `useEffect`, you should use the first `useEffect` to do all your stuff, also you should pass an empty array to `useEffect` in order to be executed one time.

```
  import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
    import ListManager from "./component/manager";
    
    const App = () => {
      const [getMovies, setMovie] = useState([]);
      const [getLoading, setLoading] = useState(true);
      useEffect(() => {
        fetch("http://my-json-server.typicode.com/bemaxima/fake-api/movies")
          .then((response) => response.json())
          .then((response) => {
            setMovie(response.map((item) => ({
              id: item.id,
              text: item.name,
              rate: item.rate,
              watched: false,
            })));
            setLoading(false);
          });
      }, []);
    
      if (getLoading) {
        return "Please wait...";
      }
      return <ListManager movies={getMovies} />;
    };
    
    export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

1. It looks like you have a typo calling setMovise instead of setMovies.
2. I'm not sure about your second useEffect. A return in useEffect is often used
   for a cleanup function like this (from [ReactJS documentation](https://fr.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html)):

   ```
   useEffect(() => {
     const subscription = props.source.subscribe();
     return () => {
       // Clean up the subscription
       subscription.unsubscribe();
     };
   });
   ```

   I'd just put it normally in the code outside the hook before the return statements.
3. Your variable naming doesn't fit the usual convention for
   useState.

   ```
   const [getMovies, setMovie] = useState([]);
   ```

   should be

   ```
   const [movies, setMovies] = useState([])
   ```